# Need help with an OR query

Tags: mysql, perl, select

I need to catch the `password` of a specif email when the value of activation is 1 or 2

query that i am using:

```
  $stmt = $db->prepare('select password from users where email=? && activation=? or activation=?');

    $stmt->bind_param('sii', $user, $activ, $activReset );
    $stmt->execute();
```

This code catches all emails that have `activation = 2`, but my idea is only catch `mail@gmail.com` if the value of `activation` is 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a query like

```
SELECT password 
FROM users 
WHERE email = 'mail@gmail.com'
   AND ( activation = 1 OR activation = 2)
```

So, you should use something like

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('select password from users where email=? AND (activation=? OR activation=?)');
```

Answer (score 0):

bracket the **or** condition so if either is true it still works with the first check against email

```
(activation=1 or activation=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('select password from users where email=? AND (activation=? OR activation=?)');
```

Use the AND keyword, and put your two possible activation values in an encapsulated OR statement.

Answer (score 0):

Add parenthesis ?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('select password from users where email=? and (activation=? or activation=?)');
```

Answer (score 0):

The query

```
SELECT password 
FROM users 
WHERE email = 'mail@gmail.com'
   AND ( activation = 1 OR activation = 2)
```

is equivalent to:

```
SELECT password 
FROM users 
WHERE email = 'mail@gmail.com'
   AND activation IN (1, 2)
```

so, you could also have:

```
$stmt = $db->
  prepare('SELECT password FROM users WHERE email=? AND activation IN (?,?)');
```

No difference in performance, just a bit shorter. It may be helpful if you have not two but a lot of OR conditions for the same field.